# JBoss AS 7 reference to class in other module in this same ear

Tags: jboss

Hello i try to migrate from jboss 4.2.3 to jboss 7 and i have some issue. My question is How can i point a class in other jar(ChartGenerateVariables.class in dts.jar), when it's needed in war(dts.war). How edit war that he know about needed class in other module(this time in jar file) and other question is how resolve this error  could not load entity class 'com.recglobal.dts.model.views.PlanSalesValue' with PersistenceUnitInfo.getNewTempClassLoader(). About this issue i don' have any clue couse this time it's not a jar file or something but its own class, only that it is a @Entity. MAybe some will now something about that.

```
12:19:26,839 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."dts.ear"."dts.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."dts.ear"."dts.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "dts.war" of deployment "dts.ear"

    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_15]

***Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.recglobal.dts.chart.SalesGoalChartServlet***
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEModuleClassDescription$DefaultConfigurator.configure(EEModuleClassDescription.java:176)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEClassConfigurationProcessor$1.compute(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:147)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEClassConfigurationProcessor$1.compute(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:40)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEApplicationDescription.getClassConfiguration(EEApplicationDescription.java:183)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription.createConfiguration(ComponentDescription.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]

    ... 5 more

**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/recglobal/dts/chart/ChartGenerateVariables**
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) [:1.6.0_15]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]

    ... 13 more

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.recglobal.dts.chart.ChartGenerateVariables from [Module "deployment.dts.ear.dts.war:main" from Service Module Loader]**
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320) [:1.6.0_15]
    ... 18 more


12:19:31,436 INFO  [org.jboss.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) starting Persistence Unit Service 'dts.ear/dts.jar#dts'

12:19:34,804 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.0.CR2}

12:19:34,868 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH00412:Hibernate Core {4.0.0.CR2}

12:19:34,991 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH00206:hibernate.properties not found

12:19:34,992 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH00021:Bytecode provider name : javassist

12:19:35,185 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH00204:Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [

    name: dts

    ...]

12:19:35,250 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."dts.ear/dts.jar#dts": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."dts.ear/dts.jar#dts": Failed to start service

    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1780) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_15]

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_15]

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_15]

**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: vfs:/D:/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/jboss-7.0.2/bin/content/dts.ear/dts.jar/**

    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:849)

    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:591)

    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)

    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitService.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitService.java:143)

    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitService.start(PersistenceUnitService.java:77)

    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]

    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]

    ... 3 more

**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not load entity class 'com.recglobal.dts.model.views.PlanSalesValue' with PersistenceUnitInfo.getNewTempClassLoader()**

    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getClassesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:152)

    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:479)

    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:846)

    ... 9 more

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.recglobal.dts.model.views.PlanSalesValue from [Module "deployment.dts.ear.dts.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]**

    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)

    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)

    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)

    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)

    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getClassesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:148)

    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got simple error :
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.recglobal.dts.chart.ChartGenerateVariables from [Module "deployment.dts.ear.dts.war:main" from Service Module Loader]**

That mean you havent got this class in your classpath.

In ear package you have got war , ejb and alco `client` jar. But in JEE6 there is good practice hold all jar into lib directory. So all jar in lib dir have got global visible for other package war , ejb .. .

For example we are delete arr jar dependencies from war package, because we have got multiple war`s so our project might be very heavy. We copy all jar dependencies into lib ear folder.

In maven you just simple add :

```
 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
```

and in your ear pom set skinnywar

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 7 has a new module system, so modules are not visible by default anymore, which is great, because now you can explicitly control the dependencies.
All you have to to is adding the dependencies to your Manifest file.

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html